# Using host names in `pg_hba.conf`?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, authentication

According to the PostgreSQL documentation:

> A host name specification that starts with a dot (.) matches a suffix
>   of the actual host name. So .example.com would match foo.example.com
>   (but not just example.com).

So I put this line in `pg_hba.conf` and restarted PostgreSQL:

```
hostssl market_data market_data_access .horsholm.dk md5
```

Then I attempt to connect to the database:

```
psql "postgresql://market_data_access@<server-IP>:5433/market_data?sslmode=require"
```

Instead of a password prompt, I get this:

```
psql: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "195.249.206.131", user "market_data_access", database "market_data", SSL on
```

Just to check, I make reverse DNS look-up of the IP address listed in the error message:

```
$ host 195.249.206.131
131.206.249.195.in-addr.arpa is an alias for 131.129-190.206.249.195.in-addr.arpa.
131.129-190.206.249.195.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer kommune.horsholm.dk.
$
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try to connect using the hostname instead of the IP, in your `psql` line?

Answer (score 9):

It's not sufficient that `195.249.206.131` resolves to `kommune.horsholm.dk` that matches the wildcard.

After checking that, Postgres will try to resolve `kommune.horsholm.dk` and find that it doesn't resolve to `195.249.206.131` (as it doesn't resolve
at all in this particular case)

```
$ host kommune.horsholm.dk
Host kommune.horsholm.dk not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

[Doc quote](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html):

> If a host name is specified (anything that is not an IP address range
>   or a special key word is treated as a host name), that name is
>   compared with the result of a reverse name resolution of the client's
>   IP address (e.g., reverse DNS lookup, if DNS is used). Host name
>   comparisons are case insensitive. If there is a match, then a forward
>   name resolution (e.g., forward DNS lookup) is performed on the host
>   name to check whether any of the addresses it resolves to are equal to
>   the client's IP address. If **both directions match**, then the entry is
>   considered to match

Comment: How can I tell which of the two requirements are not satisfied for my dns?

Answer (score 0):

The reverse DNS look up for the IP `195.249.206.131` did not resolve to a host with name `*.horsholm.dk`. If we study the output of your `host 195.249.206.131` command, you can see that the response does not contain an exact mapping for the IP to the host (All you are getting is a range of IPs) . A successful reverse DNS look up would look like below:

```
host 10.29.62.87
87.62.29.10.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer vm-test1.vpc.dev.net.
```